# В чем смысловая разница: В городе тихо — Город тихий?

Tags: семантика, прилагательные, смысл, наречия

Какая разница по смыслу:

В городе тихо.
Город тихий.

Answer (score 2):

**В городе тихо**: это *временная* ситуация (наступила ночь, жители разъехались на лето, закончилась суета с выборами мэра и т. п.).

**Город тихий**: в нём тихо *всегда* (людей  мало, нет транспортного шума, туда мало приезжают, нет политический страстей и т. п.).